# I have a error on "vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\Uri.php:72" file

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

In my project every other pages works fine but one page giving me error. I tried to fixed it but I couldn't. I used wamp server, mysql, php laravel framework. the url is correct. please help me to fix this error.

Laravel version 7.0
PHP Version 7.2.10

Web php

`Route::get('WebSiteManagement', "WebSiteManagementController@ViewPage")->middleware('CheckUserPermission');`

Middleware

```
class CheckUserPermission
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $currentPath = $request->path();

        $pageId = DB::table('userpagemaster')
            ->where('userPermissionName', $currentPath)
            ->first();
            
        $pageID = $pageId->userPageId;
        $userGroupId = Session::get('userGroup');

        if ($userGroupId != null) {
            $menuPermissions = DB::table('userpermissionmaster')
                ->where('userGroupId', $userGroupId)
                ->get()
                ->pluck('userPageId');

            Session::put('menuPermissions', $menuPermissions);

            $pagePermission = DB::table('userpermissionmaster')
                ->where('userGroupId', $userGroupId)
                ->where('userPageId', $pageID)
                ->first();

            if ($pagePermission) {

                if ($pagePermission->readOnly != '') {
                    $pagePermissionReadOnlyCheck = $pagePermission->readOnly;
                } else {
                    $pagePermissionReadOnlyCheck = 'null';
                }

                if ($pagePermission->readWrite != '') {
                    $pagePermissionReadWriteCheck = $pagePermission->readWrite;
                } else {
                    $pagePermissionReadWriteCheck = 'null';
                }

                $request->attributes->add(['readOnly' => $pagePermissionReadOnlyCheck, 'readWrite' => $pagePermissionReadWriteCheck]);

                return $next($request);
            } else {

                return redirect('403Page');
            }
        } else {

            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public function ViewPage()
    {
        $readOnly = \Request::get('readOnly');
        $readWrite = \Request::get('readWrite');

        return view('websiteManagement')->with(['readOnly' => $readOnly, 'readWrite' => $readWrite]);
    }
```

Error
[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Instead of image, show [controller's method] code that calls view file.

Comment: you will need to give us more information. Like what you are trying to achieve. your route example, your php version, Which package you are using, Controller methods etc. We cant just give you answer based on your current question

Comment: @Deepesh Thapa    I have added more details

Comment: please do not put up pictures of code, code is text, add it to your question in a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is that your requested URL does not exist. Here are only some ideas:

1. Check to see if there is ssl authentication from time to time, http and https access configuration items in guzzle
2. Is the URL parameter address correct
3. Is the permission setting correct

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I was using aws s3 bucket url and configuration are wrong!